# Is it possible to notify a File[] resource in Puppet and trigger resources subscribed to that file?

Tags: puppet

We're using Puppet to manage an OpenStack installation.  OpenStack
consists of a number of loosely connected parts, all communicating via
AMQP.  Several of the parts use a common configuration file
(`/etc/nova/nova.conf`), so a typical service resource looks like
this:

```
service { 'openstack-nova-network':
  ensure    => running,
  enable    => true,
  subscribe => File['/etc/nova/nova.conf'],
}
```

This all works great.

Now we're using Puppet to install a hotfix to some of the underlying
Python code.  When we replace one of the Python source files, we would
like to restart the services that make use of it.  In general, this is
exactly the same set of services that are subscribed to
`/etc/nova/nova.conf`.

I was hoping I could do this take advantage of the existing
dependencies by notifying the file, like this...

```
file { '/path/to/some/file':
  source => 'puppet:///.../',
  notify => File['/etc/nova/nova.conf'],
}
```

...but this didn't appear to work.  Other than putting in explicit
`notify` entries for every service, is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE**

You know, I'm beginning to suspect my question wasn't entirely clear. I'd like to apologize for the confusion and try to make my request a little more explicit:

I realize I can do this with a set of explicit dependencies, either as `subscribe` values on the services or `notify` values on the installed files.  The problem is that this means maintaining an M*N matrix of dependencies.  Introducing a new file means either:

- Updating M `service` resources, or
- Updating N `file` resources

This sort of repetitive copy-and-paste work is prone to errors, especially when multiple people are responsible for the configuration.

One option would be to maintain a central list of services:

```
$services = [ service1, service2, service ]
```

Because then I could do this:

```
file { '/usr/lib/python/glance/notifier/notify_qpid.py':
  notify => Service[$services],
}
```

But that's not going to work, because the list of services is different on different hosts.  Possibly I can flip this around and maintain a list of "hotfix" files:

```
$hotfix_files = [
  '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/glance/notifier/notify_qpid.py',
  '/root/puppet/modules/openstack/files/nova/impl_qpid.py',
]
```

And then update all the service definitions once:

```
service { 'openstack-nova-network':
  ensure    => running,
  enable    => true,
  subscribe => [
    File['/etc/nova/nova.conf'],
    File[$hotfix_files],
  ]
}
```

But this still requires manually maintaining the list of modified files.

What I really want to do is say, "notify all the services that are subscribed to `/etc/nova/nova.conf`".

Comment: How are the hotfix files being deployed? With Puppet as `File` resources? As packages? Without Puppet? I assume you've thought of the hacky solution of making a whitespace change to `nova.conf` to trigger this? ;-)

Comment: As `file` resources...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main thing you are after, "notify all the services that are subscribed to /etc/nova/nova.conf", doesn't seem to be possible with `file`-resources. But, it works with `exec`-resources, with `refreshonly`-parameter. (Just tested similar configuration with *Puppet 2.7.11*). You must add a dummy `exec`-resource:

```
exec {'dummy-nova-refresh':
    command     => "/bin/true",
    refreshonly => true,
}
```

When the command is run, `exec` sends notification to all its subscribers. And `refreshonly`-parameter makes sure that command is run only on refresh.

Subscribe all services to this Exec:

```
service { 'openstack-nova-network':
    ensure    => running,
    enable    => true,
    subscribe => Exec['dummy-nova-refresh'],
}
```

And use notify from all file-resources. (Do this also for `/etc/nova/nova.conf`, or specify it in the subscribe list for each `service`):

```
file { '/path/to/some/file':
    source => 'puppet:///.../',
    notify => Exec['dummy-nova-refresh'],
}
```

And done. A change in any file triggers a refresh in all services subscribed to `'dummy-nova-refresh'`.

Comment: what a great idea... showing once more how creative one has to be with puppet....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really an expert on neither both technologies, but I think you have to subscribe the service you want to restart to the replaced file. Something like:

```
  configfile { "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf":
    source => "/httpd/httpd.conf",
    mode => 644,
  }

  service { httpd:
    running => true,
    subscribe => file["/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"]
  }
```

Not sure if this syntax is properly written but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: So I think maybe you didn't understand the question.  The services are already subscribed to the configuration file...the question is whether it's possible to take advantage of this relationship when changing another file, or whether I need an explicit subscribe/notify for each service (for each file that is changed).

Comment: Sorry my bad...I didn't. As far as I know you have to do it for each one of your services/files.

Comment: I just found some information about defining packages which might be of some help: http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/restart-a-service-when-a-file-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

```
service { 'openstack-nova-network':
  ensure    => running,
  enable    => true,
  subscribe => [
               File['/etc/nova/nova.conf'],
               File['/path/to/some/file'],
               ],
}
```

That should work.